# passport.authenticate is not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, passport.js

Hey guys I am a beginner and I am making a simple login and register page using nextjs as front end and an express server as backend. For the authentication I am using passportjs. Here is my index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const session = require('express-session');
const passport=require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose=require("passport-local-mongoose");
const flash=require("connect-flash");
// const GoogleStrategy=require("passport-google-oauth20");
const findOrCreate=require("mongoose-findorcreate");
const next = require("next");
var cors = require('cors')

const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
  secret:"Our little secret.",
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cors({
  origin:"*"
}));
app.use(flash());



mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/simpleLoginDB",{useNewUrlParser:true});


const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  username:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  password:String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);


const User=mongoose.model("User",userSchema);


passport.use(User.createStrategy());


passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      return cb(null, {
        id: user.id,
        username: user.username
      });
    });
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  });







app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',{failureMessage:true,failureFlash:{type:'error',message:'Inavlid email or passowrd.'}}),
(req, res) => {

  console.log("hi");
  if(req.user)
  {
    res.json({
      email:req.user.username,
      error:null
    });
  }
  else
  {
    res.json({
      email:null,
      error:req.flash('error')
    });
  }
});


app.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
  User.register({username:req.body.email},req.body.password,function(err,user){
    if(err){
      res.json({email:null,error:"User already registered."});
    }
    else{
      passport.authenticate('local')(req,res,function(){
        console.log("hi");
        res.json({
          email:req.user.username,
          error:null
        })
      })
    }
  })
})

app.listen(3001,()=>{
  console.log("Server running on port 3001.")
})
```

Here is my register page from where I use axios to make a post request

```
"use client"


import axios from 'axios';
import '../styles/form.css';
import React,{useState} from 'react';



const Register = (event) => {



    const [email,setEmail]=useState("");
    const [passowrd,setPwd]=useState("");
    const [error,setError]=useState("");


    function handleChange(event){
        const newValue=event.target.value;
        event.target.name==="email"?setEmail(newValue):setPwd(newValue);
    }


    const handleSubmit=async(event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData=new FormData();
        formData.append("email",email);
        formData.append("password",passowrd);

        await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/register',formData,{
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        }).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res.data);
            if(res.data.email){
                localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn","true");
                localStorage.setItem("userEmail",res.data.email);
                window.location.href="http://localhost:3000/secret";
            }
            else{
                setError(res.data.error);
            }
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
      Register
      </h1>
      <p className='error'>{error}</p>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type='text'
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
        />
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type='password'
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={passowrd}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register
```

I am able to register a new user but after that the passport.authenticate does not work and I get a bad request error from axios. I experience the problem case with login.

```
"use client"

import '../styles/form.css'
import axios from 'axios';
import React,{useState} from 'react';




const Login = () => {


    const [email,setEmail]=useState("");
    const [pwd,setPwd]=useState("")
    const [error,setError]=useState("");

    

    const handleSubmit=async(event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();

       
        
        const formData=new FormData();
        formData.append("email",email);
        formData.append("password",pwd);

        setEmail("");
        setPwd("");

        await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login',formData,{
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        }).then((res)=>{
            if(res.data.email){
                localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn","true");
                localStorage.setItem("userEmail",res.data.email);
                window.location.href="http://localhost:3000/secret";
            }
            else{
                setError(res.data.error);
            }
        }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err);
        })
            

    }

    function handleChange(event){
        const newValue=event.target.value;
        event.target.name==="email"?setEmail(newValue):setPwd(newValue);
    }

  return (

    <div className="container">
      <h1>
      Login
      </h1>
      <p className='error'>{error}</p>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type='text'
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
        />
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type='password'
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={pwd}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login
```

Why is this? I have previously used passport in an express app without nextjs and it worked that time. How can I rectify this?

I tried to pass the user details after authentication, from the req.user. But the whole block doesn't execute and I get an axios error saying bad request.